# How to draw an image similar to a periodic function (f [x+1]=2 f [x])?

Tags: functions

The definition domain of function f [x] is R, satisfying that f[x+1]=2f[x],

and when x belongs to (0, 1], f [x]=x(x-1).

If for any x  belongs to (-[Infinity], m], there is f [x]>=-8/9, find the value range of m

1. How to draw an image of the function f [x] within a certain interval

2.How to calculate the value of m?

The image roughly looks like this:

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := 2^Floor[x]  Mod[x, 1]  (Mod[x, 1] - 1)
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]
Grid[Table[{n < x < n + 1, 
   Expand@FullSimplify[f[x], Assumptions -> n < x < n + 1]}, {n, -5, 
   5}], Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

- For `x<0`,we rewrite `f[x+1]=2f[x]` to `f[x]=f[x+1]/2;

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := x (x - 1); /; 0 < x <= 1;
f[x_] := 2 f[x - 1] /; x >= 1;
f[x_] := f[x + 1]/2 /; x < 0
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
f[x_] := x (x - 1); /; 0 < x <= 1;
f[x_] := 2 f[x - 1] /; x >=1;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: If for any x belongs to (-[Infinity], m], there is f [x]>=-8/9, find the value range of m

Comment: How can I draw an image when x<0?

Comment: Why can't I change x<0 to x<=0 to draw a function graph?
```Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := x (x - 1); /; 0 < x <= 1;
f[x_] := 2 f[x - 1] /; x >= 1;
f[x_] := 1/2 f[x + 1] /; x <= 0;
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]```
The prompt message is:```TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]```

Answer (score 7):

```
Plot[With[{qr = QuotientRemainder[x, 1]}, 
  2^First[qr] Last[qr] (Last[qr] - 1)], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also, `Plot[2^IntegerPart[x] FractionalPart[x] (FractionalPart[x] - 1), {x, 0, 3}]`

Comment: If for any x belongs to (-[Infinity], m], there is f [x]>=-8/9, find the value range of m

Comment: I don't think you can say $\forall x \in (-\infty,m] .\exists x . \ \text{such that}\ f(x) \ge -8/9$. That you wrote "there is f[x] >= -8/9" does not change the fact that $x$ is already quantified by "for any x." Did you mean "Find m such that for all x in (-infinity, m], f(x) >= -8/9"?

Comment: It means that for all x within this interval, its corresponding function values are greater than or equal to -8/9

Comment: Perhaps `First@Solve[2^IntegerPart[x] FractionalPart[x] (FractionalPart[x] - 1) == -8/9 && 0 <= x <= 3, x, Reals]`

Comment: Also: `Plot[2^Floor[x] Mod[x, 1] (Mod[x, 1] - 1), {x, 0, 3}]`

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_?NumericQ] := x (x - 1); /; 0 < x <= 1;
f[x_?NumericQ] := 2 f[x - 1] /; x >= 1;

xVal = Table[
  x /. FindRoot[f[x] == -8/9, {x, #}][[1]] & /@
   {n + 0.25, n + 0.75},
  {n, {2, 3}}]

(* {{2.33333, 2.66667}, {3.12732, 3.87268}} *)

f2[x_] = 
 ConditionalExpression[f[x], Or @@ (#[[1]] <= x <= #[[2]] & /@ xVal)]

(* ConditionalExpression[f[x], 
 2.33333 <= x <= 2.66667 || 3.12732 <= x <= 3.87268] *)

Plot[{f[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 4},
 Filling -> 2 -> Axis,
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04],
 GridLines -> {None, {-8/9}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I draw an image when x<0?